# Need a greedy address range in sed

Tags: sed

I have a bash script and I'm working with Vim. This script appends data to a file before the end of the final fold by copying the file with the final `# }}}` then appending the new data followed by a new `# }}}`.  This following snippet could be so much more elegant I had a greedy address range.

```
local END=$(grep -n '# }}}'  $FILENAME   | sed -n "$ s/\([[:digit:]]*\)\(.*\)/\1/p ")
let END=$END-1
sed -n "1, $END {p}" $FILENAME  > $TEMPFILE
```

In theory if sed supported a '--greedy-address-range' flag I could use this: `sed --silent --in-place --greedy-address-range "1, /# }}}/ {p}" $FILENAME`

Of course, thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: I've been attempting to get a code block into a comment without success and then the reverse the file answer arrived like, "wow, should of thought of that!"  I neglected the END must be minus one line in my in theory solution, but the reverse the file solution negates the need for that concern, though, from experience giving consideration for the white space between the hash and curly braces and the use of anchors make the thing a bit more robust!

Comment: I didn't understand if you finally preferred my solution or not. are you still interested in finding a way of doing it with line numbers?

Comment: Pardon, yes I like your solution.  Flipping the file makes for a nice way of insuring that nothing collects beneath the final fold.  I thought about this some and decided using Sed to not print from the top of the flipped file till the first closing Vim fold marker _should_ be easier on the eyes than my original 3 line solution...haven't had the time to test it yet.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well the output you need, this will do the job just as well:

```
tac $FILENAME | sed -n '/# }}}/,$p' | tac > $FILENAME
```

In order to print all lines until the **last** match, I reverse the file and then use
`sed` to print all lines from the **first** match to EOF then reverse it again.